# how do I make the dropdown appear at each of the hover buttons?

Tags: html, css

im trying to make the dropdown content box appear relative to each of the hover boxes but they all seem to appear in the top left corner. what do i do?

I am very new to html so please keep that in consideration when answering.

```
<title>Training Module</title>

<style>
    body {

        background-image: url(1.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }



    div {
        border: solid 1px rgb(31, 138, 187);
    }

    div:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropbtn {

        color: rgb(31, 138, 187);
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;

    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content p {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }


    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

</style>
```

explanation of Submission Id

explanation of File Number

Explanation of the types of categories

i need the dropdowns to appear relative in position to the hover boxes

Comment: please HTML code also. thanks

Comment: @CampooterScooter Give your `.dropdown` a position of `aboslute` instead of `relative` and then use `margin`, `top`, `left`, etc. to align them where you need them to appear. Hopefully it is the answer to your question.